# excludeAlreadyDisplayedNews tx_news TYPO3 6.2

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, tx-news

I am using TYPO3 version 6.2.12 and tx_news extension version 3.1.0 (latest). I've a news detail page which contains a news list view plugin. I mean when I click on news item, I can see the detail view of that news items and a list view of news items from the same storage folder.
My requirement is I want to exclude the current news items from the list view.

Eg: Suppose I've a news item named "Test 1". When I click on this, I can see the single view of this particular news item. Along with that I've a list view which shows other news items from the same storage folder. Eg: Test 1, Test 2 and Test 3.

I want to exclude that "Test 1" from the list view beacause currently I am in the detail view of that "Test 1" news. Similarly for the detail view of "Test 2", I want to exclude "Test 2" from the list view.

I've added the configuration;

```
plugin.tx_news.settings.excludeAlreadyDisplayedNews =1
```

Also added `<n:excludeDisplayedNews newsItem="{newsItem}"/>`in the template file.

But this is not working. Can you guys help me to solve the issue?

Answer (score 4):

To fix the problem we need to include the viewhelper in the news detail template:

```
`<n:excludeDisplayedNews newsItem="{newsItem}"/>`
```

We have to include this both in list view and detail templates.